# AWS RDS - Access denied to admin user when using GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON the_db.* TO 'the_user'@'%'

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mariadb, amazon-rds

When we try to GRANT ALL permissions to a user for a specific database, the admin (superuser) user of database receives the following error.

```
Access denied for user 'admin'@'%' to database 'the_Db'
```

After looking other questions in stackoverflow I could not find the solution. I already tried to change * -> % without success, that is the approach suggested in the following source:

http://www.fidian.com/problems-only-tyler-has/using-grant-all-with-amazons-mysql-rds

I think there is an underlying configuration on RDS so I can't grant all permissions for the users, but I don't know how to detect what is happening.

Update

After doing some workarounds I noticed that the "Delete versioning rows" permissions is the one that causes the problem. I can add all permissions but that one.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/grant/

So the only "way" I could grant other permissions was to specific each one of those with a script like this.

```
GRANT Alter ON *.* TO 'user_some_app'@'%';
GRANT Create ON *.* TO 'user_some_app'@'%';  
GRANT Create view ON *.* TO 'user_some_app'@'%';
GRANT Delete ON *.* TO 'user_some_app'@'%';
GRANT Drop ON *.* TO 'user_some_app'@'%';
GRANT Grant option ON *.* TO 'user_some_app'@'%';
GRANT Index ON *.* TO 'user_some_app'@'%';
GRANT Insert ON *.* TO 'user_some_app'@'%';
GRANT References ON *.* TO 'user_some_app'@'%';
GRANT Select ON *.* TO 'user_some_app'@'%';
GRANT Show view ON *.* TO 'user_some_app'@'%';
GRANT Trigger ON *.* TO 'user_some_app'@'%';
GRANT Update ON *.* TO 'user_some_app'@'%';
GRANT Alter routine ON *.* TO 'user_some_app'@'%';
GRANT Create routine ON *.* TO 'user_some_app'@'%';
GRANT Create temporary tables ON *.* TO 'user_some_app'@'%';
GRANT Execute ON *.* TO 'user_some_app'@'%';
GRANT Lock tables ON *.* TO 'user_some_app'@'%';
```

Comment: Show us the failing `GRANT` statement.  Check that `admin` had "GRANT" permission.

Comment: yes, please add the statement you used.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this

```
mysql -h your-rds-host-name -P 3306 -u rds-master-user -p

CREATE DATABASE sitedb;

CREATE USER 'siteuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'Password';
```

// For MySQL 5.7 or Less

```
GRANT ALL ON sitedb.* TO 'siteuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'Password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

// MariaDB 10 Up

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, CREATE VIEW, EVENT, TRIGGER, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, EXECUTE ON `sitedb`.* TO 'siteuser'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
EXIT
```

Comment: According to https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/duplicate-master-user-mysql/ the full command to grant all privileges to another user is `GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, PROCESS, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER ON *.* TO 'new_master_user'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

Comment: That's to grant Full RDS admin permission. The one I shared to create a user with full access to a DB.